# Spring WebFlux not streaming response

Tags: spring, flux, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I was expecting this code to stream events to the client (code is in Kotlin but Java is very similar)

```
@RestController
object CustomerController {
    @GetMapping("/load", produces = arrayOf("application/stream+json"))
    fun load(): Flux<String> {
        var flux = Flux.fromIterable(ResultIterable())
        flux.subscribe({println(it)})
        return flux
    }
}
```

ResultIterable is an iterable that generates a string on regular intervals. An infinite stream basically.

I don't see any output, it hangs forever.

I do see the string being printed on regular intervals (println(it)).

I am using the following curl:

```
curl -X GET   http://localhost:8080/load   -H 'accept: application/stream+json'   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'   -H 'content-type: application/stream+json'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
flux.subscribe({println(it)})
```

You subscribe to the `Flux` and consume it directly in the method.
When this `Flux` reaches the Reactor Netty HTTP container, there is nothing to consume already.

If you really would like `println()` each item, consider to use `doOnNext()` instead and really leave that `subscribe()` to the container.

Also you have to really follow Server Side Events rules:

> The server-side event stream syntax is simple. Set the "Content-Type" header to "text/event-stream".

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

So, when I do this:

```
@GetMapping("/load", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
fun load() =
        Flux.just("foo", "bar", "baz")
                .doOnNext({ println(it) })
```

I start to get Server Side Events in my connected client:

```
C:\tmp\so50823339>curl -X GET   http://localhost:8080/load
data:foo

data:bar

data:baz


C:\tmp\so50823339>
```

where at the same time I get logs on the server for the mentioned `doOnNext()`:

```
2018-06-12 17:33:37.453  INFO 6800 --- [           main] c.e.s.s.So50823339ApplicationKt          : Started So50823339ApplicationKt in 3.112 seconds (JVM running for 3.924)
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not work either, I tried with doOnNext() and removing the call altogether and it doesn't work, I get nothing on the response. Does the flux need to be flushed somehow. The call blocks and returns nothing.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some further investigations.

Comment: I have a similar issue but still stuck. Care to help ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908428/server-sent-event-eventstream-is-empty-and-only-shows-in-network-tab-when-flux-m